# protecting routes in next js with middleware + next-auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

please I am trying to protect some routes with the NextJS middleware if I am not authenticated, I am using next-auth for authentication and from the documentation this is what it says the middleware.ts file should be like

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
    matcher: "/room/:id*"
};
```

The issue rn is even when I am authenticated and I try to go to the room route, it redirects me to a page to sign in again and even when I do that it just redirects me back again, sort of like a loop now. I don't know what I might be doing wrong. Anyone knows what might be causing this ?

This is my next-auth API :

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { generateRandomString } from "@/utils/random";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    prompt: "consent",
                    access_type: "offline",
                    response_type: "code"
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET!,
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, profile }) {
            const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: { email: user.email! }
            });

            if (!existingUser) {
                const randomSuffix = generateRandomString();
                const firstName = user.name?.split(" ")[0].toLocaleLowerCase();
                await prisma.user.create({
                    data: {
                        email: user.email!,
                        name: user.name!,
                        username: `${firstName}#${randomSuffix}`,
                        image: user.image || profile?.image || null
                    }
                });
            }

            return true;
        },

        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id;
            }

            return token;
        }
    }
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```